# why the icon did not show in createMaterialTopTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpTv2.png)

```
const RootNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({

Page1: {screen: Page1,
  navigationOptions:{
    tabBarLabel:'Page4',
    tabBarIcon: () => (
      <Icon name="roket" color={tintColor} size={24}></Icon>

    )
}},
```

Comment: can you please mention the version of react-navigation and your example in expo snack or more code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'roket' icon for the Ionicons package. You are passing the name wrong.

Try this:

```
<Icon name="rocket" color={tintColor} size={24}></Icon>
```

You can search the icons here: https://ionicons.com/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to set icon in navigationOptions, use defaultNavigationOptions

```
const RootNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Page1: {screen: Page1},
  Page2: {screen: Page2},
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    tabBarIcon: () => {
      const {routeName} = navigation.state;
      let iconName;
      if (routename === "Page1"){
        iconName = "ios-home";
      }
      else if (routename === "Page2"){
        iconName = "ios-add";
      }
      return <Icon name={iconName} size={24} color={tintColor} />
    },
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#ff0000',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    }
  })
}
```